# Can't load static resources from custom taglib in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp-tags

I'm experimenting with Spring Boot and I'm trying to create a simple custom Tag that acts as a wrapper for my JSPs. Although I have problems to load static resources from that Tag.

Below is my directory structure:
        .

```
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   ├── java
    │   │   │   └── com....
    │   │   ├── resources
    │   │   │   ├── application.properties
    │   │   │   ├── static
    │   │   │   |    ├── js
    │   │   │   |    ├── css
    │   │   │   |    └── libraries
    │   │   │   |          ├── jquery
    │   │   │   |                └── jquery.min.js
    │   │   │   |          ├── bootstrap
    │   │   │   |          ├── ...
    │   │   └── webapp
    │   │          └── WEB-INF
    │   │                ├── tags
    │   │                     └── main.tag
    │   │                ├── tlds
    │   │                ├── views
    │   │                     └── productDetails.jsp
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── com
```

Whenever a page loads, the content is fine because I can check the HTML of the page but the static resources fail to load giving me console errors:

```
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/product/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/product/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

An interesting thing is that when I change the resources with CDN links it works fine. Somehow this is with Spring but I can't figure out what.

---

The `main.tag` is as follows:

```
<%@ tag description="Core Page Template" %>

<%@ attribute name="header" fragment="true" required="false" %>
<%@ attribute name="jsImports" fragment="true" required="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- I've even tried all possible combinations of that link
         (e.g /libraries or /static/libraries or I moved the whole directory
         under /webapp or /webapp/WEB-INF/)
         but nothing seem to work. All the time I get 404 responses from the
         server -->
    <jsp:invoke fragment="header"/>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:doBody/>

<script src="libraries/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which I can use from a JSP like:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tt" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<tt:main>
    <jsp:attribute name="header">
            <title>Products - List</title>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        Do body....
    </jsp:body>
</tt:main>
```

Comment: is that `jqery]` only a typo in the post..or cause of  the problem?..but something is also with your "MIME checking"...do you "serve static resources" as JSON? (or who does?)

Comment: @xen593 Apologies, it was indeed a typo. Regarding your second question, I haven't specified any controllers or handlers so I guess no. Does spring create any of those automatically?

Also if I move the exact same imports in the JSP directly (and get rid of the tag usage) it works fine, the resources are loading. It looks like something is wrong when I load them from the tag. Like it changes its root path but doesn't make any sense

Comment: please use/try: `/static/libraries...` or  `static/libraries` .. in your tag.

Comment: I've already tried that (it's in a comment in the `main.tag`). Eventually they weren't even loading from the JSP. They were probably cached when I tried that. Although I managed to load them. I moved them under `webapp` directory and added a configuration property. I will add an answer explaining that. Although the question why Spring doesn't load the `/resources/static` still remains. Any idea on that?

Comment: ..also a consideration: why not using `<c:url/>` or `<spring:url/>`?

Comment: ..and maybe have you (overriden) any url mappings for `/**`? [see](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)